# archlinux cannot execute java after update

Tags: arch-linux, upgrade, java

I 've updated raspberry pi b+ arch linux via `pacman -Syyu` and now I cannot run java anymore because of following error:

```
[xxxx@pi ~]# java
-bash: /usr/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Here is `archlinux-java status` command ouput:

```
[xxx@pi ~]# archlinux-java status
Available Java environments:
  java-7-openjdk (default)
```

Here is java execution file type:

```
[xxxx@pi ~]# file /usr/lib/jvm/default/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/default/jre/bin/java: data
```

And here are some data from pacman log file:
[root@octopustest ~]# tail -n30 /var/log/pacman.log

```
[2014-12-17 05:54] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -Syyu --debug'
[2014-12-17 05:54] [PACMAN] synchronizing package lists
[2014-12-17 05:54] [PACMAN] starting full system upgrade
[2014-12-17 05:59] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -Syyu'
[2014-12-17 05:59] [PACMAN] synchronizing package lists
[2014-12-17 05:59] [PACMAN] starting full system upgrade
[2014-12-17 12:09] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -Sydd --asdeps java-runtime-common'
[2014-12-17 12:09] [PACMAN] synchronizing package lists
[2014-12-17 12:09] [PACMAN] reinstalled java-runtime-common (2-2)
[2014-12-17 12:09] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -Syyu'
[2014-12-17 12:09] [PACMAN] synchronizing package lists
[2014-12-17 12:09] [PACMAN] starting full system upgrade
[2014-12-17 12:10] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -S java-runtime-common'
[2014-12-17 12:10] [PACMAN] reinstalled java-runtime-common (2-2)
[2014-12-18 06:23] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -Syyu'
[2014-12-18 06:23] [PACMAN] synchronizing package lists
[2014-12-18 06:23] [PACMAN] starting full system upgrade
[2014-12-18 06:24] [PACMAN] upgraded tdb (1.3.1-1 -> 1.3.2-1)
[2014-12-18 06:24] [PACMAN] upgraded ldb (1.1.17-1 -> 1.1.18-1)
[2014-12-18 08:49] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -Syyu'
[2014-12-18 08:49] [PACMAN] synchronizing package lists
[2014-12-18 08:50] [PACMAN] starting full system upgrade
[2014-12-19 06:53] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -Syyu'
[2014-12-19 06:53] [PACMAN] synchronizing package lists
[2014-12-19 06:54] [PACMAN] starting full system upgrade
[2014-12-19 07:05] [PACMAN] upgraded libsystemd (217-8 -> 218-1)
[2014-12-19 07:05] [PACMAN] upgraded mpfr (3.1.2.p10-1 -> 3.1.2.p11-1)
[2014-12-19 07:05] [PACMAN] upgraded systemd (217-8 -> 218-1)
[2014-12-19 07:05] [PACMAN] upgraded systemd-sysvcompat (217-8 -> 218-1)
[2014-12-19 07:05] [PACMAN] upgraded wget (1.16-2 -> 1.16.1-1)
```

Comment: The java binary is likely the wrong arch (eg 64bit binary on a 32bit OS).

Comment: @jordanm but the system was upgraded via pacman, not hand by hand, now what?

Comment: Do you check Arch's home page before updating? In particular there was a Java comment a few months ago 
[here](https://www.archlinux.org/news/java-users-manual-intervention-required-before-upgrade/)

Comment: @bdowning, yes I did that, but still same result ...

Comment: Could you please add the output of the following `archlinux-java status` as well as `file /usr/lib/jvm/default/jre/bin/java` ? Also look for any java related comments in `/var/log/pacman.log`

Comment: I asked you to run `file` on the command to find out what type of file it is. Also simple `ls` to check permissions, and please **update/edit** your question so as to prevent running commentary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've forced java reinstall process with `pacman -S --force java_package` and now everything works ok!